# Text search inside pdf file using php

Tags: php

I have more than 200 PDF files in my website. I want to add search capability for them. If a user search for a text, i need to find all PDFs that has the matching text and need to list them.

Is there any library or a way to do that in PHP?

Comment: Sounds like fun. Is there a question?

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/ good luck

Comment: I just love these things :))

Comment: i tried fpdf.. but there is no option for text search

Comment: @Arunsankar Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: yeah.. when upload a pdf file fetch the content  and insert the data's to table field... when users search the text from site (%LIKE% search from table) , we can show the particular pdf